# Array into object undefined

Tags: vue.js

I'm using VueJs with Vuetify and have this code:

data() {
    return {
      valid: false,
      sequence: [],
      test: {
        name: "",
        description: "",
        ani: "",
        environment: ["QA", "PROD"],
        steps: [
          {
            sequence: this.sequence,
            interaction: "",
            expected: "",
            description: "",
            validPlaySequence: false
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  },

When running and output test.steps on console show this:

```
sequence: undefined
```

Why?

Comment: this.sequence you should use

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `this.sequence` is created at the same time with the `this.steps`. It's like writing `var foo = {bar: 'baz', barTwo: foo.bar}`.

You can solve this by moving `steps` initialisation to `created()` or make `computed` property.